# modifying items in a concurrentbag + C#

Tags: c#

I am keeping a collection of objects in a concurrent bag. depending on the received input, I want to modify these objects. How can this be done? I cannot use trytake because it is removing the item. I am not sure if trypeek would iterate through the collection. OTOH, copying the items to an array would not work because then the objects are read only. Please help

Comment: you you mean you want to change the set of objects (i.e. so that different objects are in the bag), or do you want to *mutate* individual objects? i.e. so the same objects but now with different values?

Comment: I want to mutate individual objects so the same objects now have different values

Comment: @sura - then @Roy has the truth of it; there is no magic way of making the objects thread-safe (unless you explicitly code them to be); taking then out, altering, and re-adding seems the safest and most pragmatic option.

Comment: @Roy - yeah i also noticed that it is pretty low. what should I do to increase it?

Comment: @sura - Accept correct answers to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify items in-place, you have to take them out, modify them and put them back in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to roll your own thread-save colletction. TryPeek returns an item, but in no way ensures that no other thread modifies it.

Also there is no thread-safe iteration.

See here: http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentbag

hth

Mario

Comment: by thread-safe iteration I do not take into account the enumerator, since this makes a snapshot of the items.